# Is the user table considered a dimension or part of fact

Tags: reporting, rdbms, data-warehouse, star-schema

I am designing a star scheme db where the fact is user login.
My dimensions are time (up to hour of day) and location (based on IP).
I have about 300k users in my system. This size grows by 5k/year.
Should the user details be part of the fact table or a dimension table onto itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User details are descriptive of the user and should be in a dimension.

Comment: Regardless of the user table size?

Comment: Not regardless of table size, but it doesn't sound like you've got millions of users here. You won't want to repeat the user details in a fact table, that's for sure. Best to have a nice small surrogate key in the fact table, keeping it compact.

Answer (score 2):

Facts are usually created for business activities.

I believe your business activity (in this scenario) would be a user logging at a particular time.

Fact table: Fact_User_Login
Dim Tables:Dim_User,Dim_Date_Time, Dim_Location

This is just an example.

Hope that helps

Cheers
Nithin

Comment: it helps -> tnx